# On my Android phone (Pixel 7) what is "-5" stealthily using several gigabytes of mobile data? (It's not the hotspot)

Tags: android, google-pixel

Android BatteryStats shows something called "-5" rapidly using gigabytes of mobile data, but it's not the hotspot.

Per another post I used the command "adb shell dumpsys batterystats" to get the battery statistics of my Pixel 7 since it got a full charge this morning.

Just like yesterday, I see a HUGE amount of mobile data usage by "-5":

```
  -5:
    Mobile network: 11.79GB received, 7.52GB sent (packets 12621645 received, 10920090 sent)
    Mobile radio active: 26m 25s 111ms (26.9%) 15x @ 0.0673 mspp
       Cellular Sleep time:  0ms (0.0%)
       Cellular Idle time:   0ms (0.0%)
       Cellular Rx time:     15m 0s 836ms (6.7%)
       Cellular Tx time:     
         less than 0dBm:  28s 382ms (0.2%)
         0dBm to 8dBm:  30s 874ms (0.2%)
         8dBm to 15dBm:  4s 799ms (0.0%)
         15dBm to 20dBm:  1s 926ms (0.0%)
         above 20dBm:  17s 538ms (0.1%)
    (nothing executed)
```

This is in just under 4 hours.  Yesterday it said 86GB used(!) in just under 9 hours.

Other users in the past have attributed this to the hotspot, but I haven't had the hotspot on at all today (or yesterday).  My total hotspot usage in the Settings app shows, correctly, 5.45GB used since I bought the phone a couple of weeks ago.

This mysterious mobile data is also not coming out of the total mobile data usage listed in the Settings app, which is 15.02GB.  If I hadn't have been looking at battery stats (initially through a full bug report dump using Battery Historian), I wouldn't have noticed it.

I've checked apps and done malware scans and am not rooted.  Bug?  Malware?  3 letter agency?

ETA: I managed to check my mobile provider (EE)'s own metering and it's not seeing all this data transfer.  I've used 24.8GB, according to EE, since 29th April - certainly not the 86GB that the battery stats output suggested yesterday.  So surely, either whoever it is is conspiring with EE to hide the mobile traffic (I suppose plausible if I'm of interest to a security agency but I can assure you I'm pretty boring) or, something is odd with the battery stats output.

Edit2: I've seen at least one user suggest on reddit that it's Google operational traffic and doesn't normally get counted by the mobile provider or the visible counter in Android, and because I'm using the "buggy" vanced microg (from a legit source) for Revanced (also legit from github, no pre-patched apks) that the microg is going all screwy.  But eh, what kind of bug transfers that much data? I'm not convinced.

Comment: This site is for programming related questions. Power user/end user questions about Android belong on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=identify+app+using+data)

Comment: Alright.  For what it's worth it seems to indeed be Vanced Microg.  Uninstalled it and problem went away.  Can't speak for REvanced but this one seems shady.